# Google Map - infowindow hyperlink

Tags: apex, javascript, html

I've set up an embedded google map in my VF page that displays all records within x km. I've added info windows to each of these, with the aim that the user can click on the link in the infowindow and it'll redirect them to that records detail page. I'm using:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div style="font-size: 8pt;">' + '<b>' + siteName + '</b>' + '</br>' + status + '</br><a href="' + siteLink + '">Load Site</a>'
        });
```

where siteLink is the id of the clicked marker. However, this redirects me to:

https://c.cs7.visual.force.com/apex/a0HM0000005AQFLMA4

rather than:

https://c.cs7.visual.force.com/a0HM0000005AQFLMA4

and so gives me an error. Any ideas how to get round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try "/siteName" (a leading slash)?  That would usually get a link to the root URL, ignoring the /apex path.

Comment: Can you share the code since I am trying to achieve the same results?
Thanks
Roger Francis

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
              html { height: 100% }
              body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
              #map-canvas { height: 100% }
        </style>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
            <script>
            var map;

            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000),
                    zoom: 5
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);


            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
        <script>
            function loadHotels() {
            var contentString = null;
            var count = 0;
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.SalesRep.findAll}',
            function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                    var id = result[i].Id;
                    var name = result[i].Name;
                    var addr= result[i].Address__c;
                    var lat = result[i].Location__Latitude__s;
                    var lng = result[i].Location__Longitude__s;

                    contentString = 'Name : '+result[i].Name +'<br/>'+'Address : '+ result[i].Address__c+' <br/> '+'<a href="/'+ id + '" target="_blank">Go To The Detail Page</a>';

                   // alert(contentString);
                    addMarker(id,lat, lng,contentString);
                    count++;
                }

            } else {
                alert(event.message);
            }
        },
        {escape: true}
    );
```

}

```
        function addMarker(id,lat,lng,contentString) {
       // alert('Map'+contentString);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        map: map,
        title: name 
});

   // var infowindow = null;
    //var details = 'The details of the rep</br>'+name+'</br>'+addr+'</br>'+id;
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:contentString,maxWidth:2000});
  // alert(infowindow);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    //window.top.location = '/' + id;
    //infowindow.open(map,marker);
   // infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);

});
```

}
loadHotels();

```
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="map-canvas"/>
    </body>
```

controller:

global with sharing class SalesRep{

```
@RemoteAction
global static List<SalesRep__c> findAll() {
    return [SELECT Id,Name,Address__C,Location__Latitude__s,Location__Longitude__s FROM SalesRep__c];
}
```

}

I think may be this will help you.

Comment: Can you please add some explanations about your code ?